# How to test timeouts in Temporal with Go?

Tags: temporal-workflow

Im trying to test activities timeouts, but i don’t understand how works RegisterDelayedCallback:

#### My Workflow

```
func ExamWorkflow(ctx workflow.Context, examID string) (string, error) {

    logger := workflow.GetLogger(ctx)

    logger.Info("Starting workflow for exam ", examID)

    // pass exam to AWAITING_EXAM status
    ao := workflow.ActivityOptions{
        ScheduleToStartTimeout: 1 * time.Minute,
        StartToCloseTimeout:    1 * time.Minute,
        HeartbeatTimeout:       1 * time.Minute,
        ScheduleToCloseTimeout: 1 * time.Minute,
    }
    ctxAe := workflow.WithActivityOptions(ctx, ao)
    var res string
    err := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctxAe, AwaitingExamActivity, examID).Get(ctxAe, &res)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("failed awaiting exam %s : %s", examID, err)
        return "", err
    }

    err = workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctxAe, ExamInProgressActivity, examID).Get(ctxAe, &res)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("failed inprogress exam %s : %s", examID, err)
        return "", err
    }

    logger.Info("Finishing workflow for exam %s", examID)

    return "", nil
}
```

#### My Activities

```
func AwaitingExamActivity(ctx context.Context, examID string) (string, error) {

    log := activity.GetLogger(ctx)
    activityInfo := activity.GetInfo(ctx)
    taskToken := activityInfo.TaskToken

    ioutil.WriteFile("./token.txt", taskToken, 0644)

    log.Info("Estado espera", "Valor token", string(taskToken))
    log.Info("Puts exam " + examID + " in AWAITING_EXAM status and takes a number for attention")

    return "", activity.ErrResultPending

}

// ExamInProgressActivity - Puts exam in EXAM_IN_PROGRESS status.
func ExamInProgressActivity(ctx context.Context, examID string) error {

    log := activity.GetLogger(ctx)
    log.Info("Puts exam ", examID, " in EXAM_IN_PROGRESS status and takes a number for attention")

    activityInfo := activity.GetInfo(ctx)
    taskToken := activityInfo.TaskToken

    ioutil.WriteFile("./token_eip.txt", taskToken, 0644)

    return activity.ErrResultPending

}
```

#### Test

```
func (s *UnitTestSuite) Test_Workflow() {

    env := s.NewTestWorkflowEnvironment()

    env.RegisterDelayedCallback(func() {
        token, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./token.txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println("en espera")
        env.CompleteActivity(token, "", nil)
    }, 10*time.Minute)

    env.RegisterActivity(AwaitingExamActivity)

    env.RegisterDelayedCallback(func() {
        token, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./token_eip.txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println("en espera")
        env.CompleteActivity(token, "", nil)
    }, 10*time.Minute)

    env.RegisterActivity(ExamInProgressActivity)

    env.ExecuteWorkflow(ExamWorkflow, "45")

    s.True(env.IsWorkflowCompleted())
    err := env.GetWorkflowResult(nil)
    s.NoError(err)

}
```

The ActivityOptions has one minute in timeout for all their attributes and the callbacks has ten minutes, but the test finish ok.

Can anyone explain me why has this behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not very familiar with Temporal, but I think you can just let activity return timeout error in test code, like mocking. You can check the samples.

Comment: is suppose RegisterDelayedCallback is for that, if i sets a time response greater than the activity timeout would be to trigger a timeout error.